# Lock Tmux Session With Vlock

Tags: command-line, lock-screen, lock, tmux

I have just installed `tmux` and `vlock`. When I try to perform the `lock-session` command, my terminal flashes and then nothing happens. Is there something in my `.tmux.conf` that must be added to tell `tmux` that I have a locking utility? If so, what is it?

In other words:

How can I do `lock-session` with `tmux`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put the following in the `.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g lock-command vlock
```

Comment: Just in case, the package/program `vlock` may not be installed by default (e.g.`Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS`). The following, usually, should achieve it: `sudo apt-get install vlock;`.

Answer (score 4):

I have the following `tmux.conf` lines:

```
# Enable locking
set -g lock-command vlock
set -g lock-after-time 0 # Seconds; 0 = never
bind L lock-session
```

Pressing `[prefix]` + `L` (capital) locks my session.

Related [How can I lock just the current client?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/406188/143394)